# python pandas remove duplicates in series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a function to enforce that the index is unique or is it only possibly to handle this in python 'itself' by converting to dict and back or something like that?

As noted in the comments below: python pandas is a project built on numpy/scipy.

to_dict and back works, but I bet this gets slow when you get BIG.

```
In [24]: a = pandas.Series([1,2,3], index=[1,1,2])

In [25]: a
Out[25]: 
1    1
1    2
2    3

In [26]: a = a.to_dict()

In [27]: a
Out[27]: {1: 2, 2: 3}

In [28]: a = pandas.Series(a)

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
1    2
2    3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `last()`

```
In [279]: s
Out[279]: 
a    1
b    2
b    3
b    4
e    5

In [280]: grouped = s.groupby(level=0)

In [281]: grouped.first()
Out[281]: 
a    1
b    2
e    5

In [282]: grouped.last()
Out[282]: 
a    1
b    4
e    5
```

Comment: In pandas 0.8 and up I think you can have duplicate indices ... i.e. s = Series([1,2,1], index=['a','a','b']). to_dict and back does the trick but it seems like there should be an option or something to handle this or maybe it's something to do with the way I'm constructing the Series.

Comment: thatnks for clearing the question. it's a pitty you missed Wes McKinney by couple of hours time...

Comment: I believe I clarified //because// of Wes McKinney's comment :)

Answer (score 7):

BTW we plan on adding a `drop_duplicates` method to Series like `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` in the near future.

Comment: Added since then, but for the OP's case with different values it doesn't do anything (`pd.Series([1,2,3], index=[1,1,2]).drop_duplicates()` -> `1: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3`), so root's answer should be used.

Comment: FWIW, `df.drop_duplicates` has been implemented.

Comment: it has been implemented for Dataframes @TimMcNamara, not for Series.